# Hide all borders in MudDataGrid

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Hide all borders in MudDataGrid

How to hide all the borders in MudDataGrid?

From [this MudDataGrid with bottom borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZb5F.png)

To [MudDataGrid desired result (in paint) :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIrN0.png)

```
Bordered="false"
```

is also not working.

Also, I tried to override with some styles, but not helping.

Any help would be appriciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom classes to override the elements.

```
<style>
    .no-borders > td, .no-borders > tr > th
    {
        border:none;
    }
</style>
<MudDataGrid RowClass="no-borders" HeaderClass="no-borders" Items="@Elements.Take(4)">
    //...
</MudDataGrid>
```

[Example snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cYGdEUYbhrMtMmSK)

Comment: Thank you.
I already tried something. similar, but I can't rid of outside borders.
In your solution, I can see that you have the same problem.

Comment: Try this `<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements.Take(4)" RowClass="no-borders" HeaderClass="no-borders" Elevation="0" Style="background:transparent;">`  set Elevation to 0 and background to transparent.